# FindMeIn Gem or output file name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

i was wondering if exist a gem which in development env display render path of file (layout, view, partials..) at the top of each html

example:

> find me in /posts/show.html.erb

i'm working co-op with a designer (with 0 rails skills) and it's our first project

if not exist a gem like this, how can display the path of each file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a gem that does it, I don't recall the name, but it might be this one:

https://rubygems.org/gems/rails_view_annotator

> The Rails View Annotator makes it easy to find out which partial
>   generated which output